# tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. The name tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecated

Tags: python-3.x, keras, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am working on a face recognition desktop application. I am using face recognition library (https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/) and deepface (https://pypi.org/project/deepface/). I am using a venv virtual environment and I can confirm that my code is correct (since it works on colab). On running the application, I get the following warning and my application crashes when encoding generation using face_recognition library is triggered. Note that the encoding generation using face_recognition works when keras is uninstalled (but Keras is required for deepface).

Warning:

```
2024-02-04 12:16:00.858406: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxx\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py:2976: The name tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy instead.
```

I am blocked because of this and any help will be appreciated.

Keras version: 2.15.0
Tensorflow version: 2.15.0

My imports:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import json
from imutils import paths
import argparse
import pickle
import cv2
import os
import face_recognition
import time
from deepface import DeepFace
from retinaface import RetinaFace
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import imutils
```

I tried playing around with versions of the deps but it did not work. I also used os.environ['TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS'] = '0' to get rid of the warning, but it did not work as well. I also tried: set TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0

P.S. I am using windows 10

Comment: Warnings do not block anything, are you sure this is the problem and not something else?

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy When I delete Keras, the embedding generation starts working. When I install it back, the embedding generation crashes.

I suspect there is something to do with dependency compatibility, and was thinking that this may be the root cause? I feel like I'm running out of ideas!

Comment: try install deepface as `pip install deepface --no-deps`. in that way, you can skip to install keras. besides, if you have tf 2.X, then keras is not mandatory for deepface.